# Console flickering on redraw

Tags: c#, console-application

I recently started coding in c#, and I wanted to make a program that draws something in the console, here is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace HelloWorld
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static readonly Random random = new Random();

            // Console width and height
            static int width = Console.WindowWidth;
            static int height = Console.WindowHeight;

            // Declare window grid
            static string[,] Grid = new string[height, width];

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                init();
                loop();

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            // Game loop

            static async void loop()
            {
                bool running = true;
                int i = 0;

                while (running)
                {
                    Grid[0, i] = "#";

                    render();

                    i++;
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }

            static void init()
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        Grid[y, x] = random.Next(0, 2) == 1? "#" : " ";
                    }
                }
            }

            static void render()
            {
                string temp = "";

                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        string current = Grid[y, x];

                        temp += current;
                    }
                    temp += "\n";
                }

                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a problem though, when I refresh the console, it flickers ever so slightly, but very noticeably. Is there a solution for this? Or a better way to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the existing content is being removed when you call `Console.Clear();`, even if it's unchanged. You're writing it back immediately, but there is enough of a delay for this to present as a flicker, as you've found.

Since you're rewriting the entire grid again every time, I would suggest you use `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);` This will move the start position for writing back to the beginning, and then it will overwrite everything without first clearing the console. This should eliminate the flicker.

```
static void render()
{
    string temp = "";

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            string current = Grid[y, x];

            temp += current;
        }
        temp += "\n";
    }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0); // reset the cursor position
    Console.Write(temp);
}
```

I would go so far as to remove the string building altogether, and just update the individual characters in the console:

```
static void render()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y); // set the position to x,y
            string current = Grid[y, x];
            Console.Write(current); // write this value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this helped me out a lot! Another question, are there any cleanup/things that you'd have done differently about my code? I've been learning c# and not sure if I'm doing it right... :)

Comment: @Coenicorn The only thing that really jumped out at me was that you're using `string` to hold a single character, so perhaps you could change your grid array from `string[,]` to `char[,]`, and then replace things like `Grid[0, i] = "#";` with `Grid[0, i] = '#';` (a char is represented by `'` whereas a string by `"`). If you want code review, there is a dedicated Stack Exchange site for it, which might be useful to you: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Note that only working code is accepted there.

Comment: Also, another question, when I build this in visual studio and run the .exe file, the characters being displayed are being seperated by an empty character, what used to be "#####" in VS becomes "# # # # #" in the .exe, do you know why?

Comment: That I don't know. It seems fine in both debug and release builds. Since your init is random, I'd suggest creating `Random` with a specific seed temporarily (e.g. `random = new Random(1);`) so that you can directly compare the same "map" when launched from VS vs launched from the EXE. It might be something to do with the console window it is being displayed in.